# Numbered Chapter

Tags: chapters, templates

What i would like is for the chapters of my book to be numbered in the ToC (which i have already achieved) AND in text such as

1 - Introduction (notice "Chapter 1 -" is missing and instead it just says "1 - "

What is happening at the moment is that ive got

```
Introduction

1.1 Section
1.2 Section

New Chapter
2.1 Section
2.2 Section
```

But instead this should be

```
1 - Introduction

1.1 Section
1.2 Section

2 - New Chapter
2.1 Section
2.2 Section
```

I am using the [masters doctoral thesis template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) from latextemplates.

Comment: Could you please make your code snippet compilable?

Comment: pew....its a lot or do you just want the .cls file instead ?

Comment: No, it would be easier if you could just provide an example document with as much code as necessary (but the least amount needed) that is compilable. That means put your code into a document, add the required packages and a test case that shows your problem. This is called MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis this is what im using,  just noticed that i already modified mine to remove chapter, but with this template it would suffice if chapter 1 - Intro for example is on the same line without the word chapter

Comment: I got it working now ! so no need anymore, thanks thou !

Comment: Why don't you leave the class file alone? Use `chapterinoneline` option.

Comment: I advice you not to bother with the class file at all, there is a copyright and licence you may be violating. https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/ Also, why don't you just follow the *Ask question* button to get to the proper place to get support for that template?

Comment: `chapterinoneline` option would give you *`1 Introduction`*, but your question requests *`1 - Introduction`*. That would be achieved by `\renewcommand{\autodot}{~-}` (untested).

Comment: @Johannes_B ive got it working, the actual cls file had everything i needed and i just added     \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
 \vspace*{25 pt}%
 {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
  \bfseries\Huge\thechapter \space -\ #1
  \par\nobreak\vspace{40 pt}}}

Comment: Please do not change the class file! It isn't yours. You are just allowed to use it. You can make any change you want in the document preamble, including redefining what you need. In this case however, i would suggest to use [a minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op has solved the problem (with a `\renewcommand`) as noted in the comments.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question as i would like to add how to solve the problem with ways the template provides.

Comment: @Johannes_B i really dont understand why youre telling me off for adding the renewcommand in the cls file, its not like im sharing it online and redistributing it again, since the copyright lies with the original author

Comment: but as you have asked me to change it, i have used your renewcommand of the capterinonline option in my preamble and left the cls file alone (reverted to its original state)

Comment: There are already dozens of this file on GitHub, most of them modified, almost none according to the license. It makes support so much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> Rule of thumb: Do not change a class or package file, it makes support  very complicated.

---

The template uses almost the default chapter formatting as the underlying  `book` class.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[
english, % ngerman for German
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: mdtDefaultPeter]

Uncommenting the global option `chapterinoneline` already gives something very close to the desired result.

[image: mdtChapterinoneline]

To get the dash, one can redefine the `\autodot` macro. There are helper macros to change the spacing as well.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[
english, % ngerman for German
chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\autodot}{~-}
\renewcommand{\chapterbelowskip}{\vspace{100pt}}
\renewcommand{\abovechapterskip}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The code above gives the result in the image below (no space above the chapter heading, a large space below it):

[image: mdtChapterSpace]

---

Note the inconsistent naming convention.

General advice: Do not use a template, rather start from scratch with a [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports) and only adding what you really need.